# Pivot_wider returning list values R

Tags: r, dataframe, organization

I have a huge data set that looks something like this:

| ID | color | number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Blue | 32 |
| 1 | Yellow | 12 |
| 1 | Red | 13 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 32 | Yellow | 15 |
| 56 | Red | 112 |
| 56 | Blue | 42 |

I want to get a data frame that looks like

| ID | Red | blue | yellow |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 13 | 32 | 12 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 32 | 0 | 0 | 15 |
| 56 | 112 | 42 | 0 |

I've tried:

```
Data %>%
pivot_wider(names_from = "color",
          values_from = "number")
```

The issue with this is I get a list. I figured this may be because of repeated rows after some research, so I removed them with:

```
data <- unique(data)
```

But alas, I still got the error message:

Warning message:
Values from `color` are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.

- Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
- Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates.

So I then tried the following code after going through several examples

```
Data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = ID, values_from = number) %>%
  select(-row)
```

Which technically worked, but gave me my IDs as column names, which wasn't what I was going for.

I think I've figured out how to rearrange this to turn my IDs back into rows, but I can't shake the feeling that I will mess something else up by doing this. The data is so large that it won't be easy by any stretch to check, and it bothers me that I can't figure this out. What am I missing here?

Comment: The data you provided is not sufficient to reproduce the warning you have. Consider using `value_fn = list` for example to silence the warning. Your data is unique, though has duplicated color for the same id. eg id 1 has blue 32 and also has blue with 24 for example. So you have 2 values within the blue cell of id 1. probably you neeed their mean, sum, etc. ie a function to aggregate them. Hence `value_fn = mean` would suffice

Comment: My issue isn't the warning, it's that I am unable to further work with the data as a list. The data is too huge to post here in its entirety. I can only think of a possible reason for my problem being that I have two repeating colors within the same ID, but can't figure out how to check for this. So do I put the value_fn = mean within the pivot_wider command, or do it separately? Thank you for your help!

Comment: You do not need to post all the data, just sufficient enough to elaborate your issue. Also what do you mean by *unable to further work with*? How do you want to aggregate the data? If you do not want to aggregate it, then use `list` as the `value_fn`

Comment: I need to merge it with other dataframes, and this has been pretty difficult to do in list form. I decided it would be easier to fix this problem. I'd be okay with averaging the two values for the same color for the same ID, but this isn't ideal--and I'm having trouble with figuring out how to do so. I figured there may be something I'm missing, because I can get the result I want (I think) in a data frame with the second block of code I posted. I get a dataframe with no error messages. The issue with this, though, is that the IDs are the column names.

Comment: Also, I would've included the suspected repeat in the data I posted, but it was only a hunch. I've been looking for the repeats but have been unable to find them, other than the rows that were direct clones (ID same-color same-number same) that I deleted

Comment: The warning is due to the replicated values and NOT duplicated values. Also if you are going to merge two tables, You could melt the other table (ie pivot_longer), join the two and then pivot_wider

Comment: Is there a way to delete these replicated values in this context? Or if not, be able to find them? I've been hunting for a way to do this. I've tried a few things but nothing is working for me. I feel like averaging them is a better solution than deleting them, but I haven't had success with what I've tried.

Comment: When using value_fn = mean, I still get a list back

Comment: you could find them you could remove them by `df %>%group_by(ID, color)%>%slice_head(n = 1)` then pivot_longer

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been working on this for hours, embarrassingly enough

Comment: That might work, but you are throwing away alot of data. I that works, then probably `value_fn = 'first'` should also work

Comment: I lost 2,000 out of 200,000. It's better than not having anything. I would love to be able to average, but I have been unable to get value_fn = mean to work

Comment: That is maybe because you have overwritten the `mean` function with another function. Consider doing `rm("mean")`

Comment: I tried removing it. I get: Error:
! Arguments in `...` must be used.
✖ Problematic argument:
• value_fn = "mean"

Comment: definitely, You have mean from a different place. Maybe just consider `base::mean` instead of just `mean`

Comment: When I looked into the error I got: 2. tidyr::pivot_wider(...)
 3. rlang `<fn>`()
 4. rlang:::check_dots(env, error, action, call)
 5. rlang:::action_dots(...)
 7. rlang action(...)

Comment: after using base::mean I get: Error:
! Arguments in `...` must be used.
✖ Problematic argument:
• value_fn = base::mean
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: I'm using it in my code as: data %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "color",
              values_from = "number",
              value_fn = base::mean)

Comment: what hapens if you use `sum/first/last/min/median/max etc`??

Comment: it should be `values_fn` not `value_fn`

Comment: I owe you big time. Thank you so much. I've had a really rough time with this. I barely get time to work with this so am still a beginner (obviously).